# Different output `as.list` for `$` vs. `dplyr::select`

Tags: r, dplyr

I encountered a behavior in R that I do not fully understand, and I was wondering if someone could give me a bit of an explanation about why these outputs are different.

I am writing a function, and I performed what I thought were more or less two equivalent operations, but the outputs gave me different shapes:

```
data("iris")
library(dplyr)

as.list(iris$Species)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] setosa
#> Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] setosa
#> Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] setosa
#> Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] setosa
#> Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] setosa
#> Levels: setosa versicolor virginica

as.list(iris %>% select(Species))
#> $Species
#>   [1] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa    
#>   [6] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa    
#>  [11] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa   
    ...
#> [146] virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica 
#> Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
```

Why are these outputs different? Why do they behave differently?

Thanks for any insights you can share!

Comment: In the first case you are converting a _vector_ to a list. In the second example you are converting a single-column _data frame_ to a list. These are not the same thing. `length(iris$Species)` is 150 (the vector has 150 elements), so you get a list with 150 length-1 elements. `length(select(iris, Species))` is 1 (the data frame has one element - a vector of 150 elements), so you get a length-1 list containing a single vector with 150 elements.

Comment: Okay I didn't realize that `$` gets a vector -- thank you!

Comment: If you use `pull` rather than `select` you'll get the same thing: `as.list(iris %>% pull(Species))`